# Unable to edit my own post without moderation (turned out to be a bug, can do it)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits

I tried to edit my own post, in this case an answer.
Please see:
[SQL Reporting Services - Cryptic Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119975/sql-reporting-services-cryptic-warnings/59393103#59393103)

The result seemed to 'save' but not display.

Is it now require that a moderator approves such a situation?  (I certainly hope not).

Otherwise, I am experiencing some sort of strange bug.

Comment: There is no edit, or pending edit on that post.....

Comment: I've seen this once in a while, usually when using the back or forward browser buttons but sometimes right after editing a post. Try reloading the page and see if the edit shows up.

Comment: I tried again and it worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement that edits to your own post be approved, whether by a moderator or anyone else.

As Patrice said in the comments, there is no edit pending on that post, and as far as the system is concerned, no edit has ever been submitted to that post at all, by anyone.

So, chances are, you just experienced a transient Internet failure. Please try to edit the post again. It should go through this time.